# Firing Anti-parallel Thyristors with continuously firing pulse-trains

Tags: thyristor

Can I use two pulse trains as describe below to fire a set of anti-parallel thyristors? Is there any potential danger in this firing scheme?

PS: I must use pulse train firing in my application.

[image]

Comment: Uhm why not simply use a TRIAC ? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRIAC  You ask about "danger", what danger? To the environment? Or do you mean "Will it work?" Yes I think it will work provided you apply the pulses for each Thyristor with the correct polarity to that Thyristor. I still think a TRIAC would be easier though, almost everyone would use a TRIAC for this switching AC. Or if you insist on Thyristors. use a bridge rectifier to make DC and switch that.

Comment: By 'danger' I meant 'misfiring' that could damage the thyristors. My application demands the use of thyristors. Cheers.

Comment: @bimpelrekkie It is how I handle my own systems -- two scrs rather than a triac. There are downsides using triacs vs this arrangement. But it would be a discussion I'd rather avoid for now, except I'll suggest there is less conflation of options and more management options. Suffice it, it's not always better with triacs. Regardless, this sounds like homework.

Comment: @HacLe: (1) No you trigger once per half-cycle. (2) The trigger has to be relative to it's cathode so you can't reference the two together.

Comment: @Transistor - why not? How about connecting a MOC3020 optotriac like this: https://i.ytimg.com/vi/miyQHCq3HRs/hqdefault.jpg

Comment: @Tudor: That's an interesting trigger arrangement that I haven't seen before. It neatly removes the common reference problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to use pulse train triggering. Actually pulse train triggering is the only way to handle inductive loads with thyristors or triacs. There is no danger at all. If you are not using pulse train triggering a DC component could flow in such situations.
Very nice explanation about pulse triggering can be found in:
http://www.datelec.fr/secteur/ST%20AN308.pdf

The pulse triggering as indicated in the drawing of OP has a high frequency in respect to the mains frequency and is required in cases of inductive loads triggering failure due to Back EMF from DC motors.

Comment: It isn't by the way. A pulse train is usually used because a pulse transformer is used to provide isolation, a nice simple solution. You can have a continuous gate current for the conduction angle if you design a circuit as such

Comment: @JonRB. A pulse train is required when you need refire the thyristor or triac within the cycle. The pulse transformer is only for isolation and has nothing to do with requiring a pulse train.

Comment: There is a difference between a pulse train at a frequency of the mains (or twice that) and that at say 10kHz. Look at what the OP has drawn

Comment: @JonRB. See my improved answer. Also read the article in the reference or at least a part of it.